# When the number of tasks are too large in spark-on-yarn-client mode, containers are failed to launch

Tags: apache-spark, task, containers, hadoop-yarn, executor

I'm testing spark-sql on hive running some sophisticated sql statements. When the largest number of my jobs are too large, say over 70000 in my situation, the application will stuck for a while and then throw the following error messages:

> 6/07/06 17:53:20 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint:
>   Container marked as failed: container_1466092136376_0229_01_000002 on
>   host: 10.17.124.127. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from
>   container-launch. Container id: container_1466092136376_0229_01_000002
>   Exit code: 1 Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
>
> 16/07/06 17:53:20 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message
>   [message = RemoveExecutor(1,Container marked as failed:
>   container_1466092136376_0229_01_000002 on host: 10.17.124.127. Exit
>   status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch. Container id:
>   container_1466092136376_0229_01_000002 Exit code: 1 Stack trace:
>   ExitCodeException exitCode=1:     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1 )] in 1 attempts
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler
>   or it has been stopped.   at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postLocalMessage(Dispatcher.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.removeExecutor(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(YarnSchedulerBackend.scala:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:116)
>     at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:204)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:215)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

how to avoid the problem?

Comment: please add the executor's log also (e.g. from Spark UI)

Comment: yes this is exactly the executor's log. Also I have checked yarn's log, but there is no additional messages but "Container marked as failed" and "Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch" which are the same as above.

Comment: I am facing the same issue too. I tried few things for "NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = " going through few blogs but didnt help.